# How do you send raw byteArray as body of post request in khttp?

Tags: java, kotlin, httpclient, backend

From the source of khttp it seems that you cant send raw byteArray as body of request because it always adds paddding to it. I've also tried using the Fuel library but it requires coroutines that conflict with my dependencies.

Does anyone know how to either 1) send raw bytes body in khttp or 2) another library that does

Answer (score 1):

You're right. [As per their code](https://github.com/jkcclemens/khttp/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/khttp/requests/GenericRequest.kt#L122) if the data you're sending is not file or stream it will be `toString()'d` which is not what you want. So, you may try providing a `ByteArrayInputStream` instead of `ByteArray`:

```
val response = post(
    "https://httpbin.org/anything",
    data = ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3)),
    headers = mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/octet-stream")
)
```

Thus you'll send bytes as is.

BTW, [khttp repo](https://github.com/jkcclemens/khttp) seems to be abandoned, so you'd better switch to another lib. Basically, any HTTP library can send raw bytes. As for the Fuel: it follows modular architecture and does not 100% require you to use coroutines:

```
val (request, response, result) = "https://httpbin.org/anything".httpPost()
    .body(byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3))
    .header(mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/octet-stream"))
    .response()

println(response)
```

You'll see your byte array (in `data`):

```
<-- 200 (https://httpbin.org/anything)
Response : OK
Length : 564
Body : ({
    "args": {}, 
    "data": "\u0001\u0002\u0003", 
    "files": {}, 
    "form": {}, 
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2", 
        "Accept-Encoding": "compress;q=0.5, gzip;q=1.0", 
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache", 
        "Connection": "close", 
        "Content-Length": "3", 
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream", 
        "Host": "httpbin.org", 
        "Pragma": "no-cache", 
        "User-Agent": "Java/1.8.0_192"
    }, 
    "json": null, 
    "method": "POST", 
    "origin": "1.2.3.4", 
    "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
})
```

Comment: Found out that my conflicting dependencies was because I was using experimental coroutines. Upgraded Kotlin to 1.3.10 etc and it work fine. Thanks